# How to link a droplink to a Treelist in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, datasource, sitecore7, treelist

I'm trying to figure out how I can link a `Droplink` to the selected items in a `Treelist`. 
I have a field `Theme`, which is the `Treelist`, and a field `MasterTheme`, which is the `Droplink`.

I should be able to select a master-theme in the `Droplink`, which is filled with the selected data from the `Treelist`.

I'm pretty new to Sitecore, and I'm not familiar with Custom classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `getLookupSourceItems`-pipeline for this. With a `Droplink` you can specify a Sitecore query as source. And with the `getLookupSourceItems` you can change the source at runtime. The following processor checks the items selected in the `Treelist` and create a Sitecore query which includes all the items selected in the `Treelist`.

```cs
public class LookupItemsFromField
{
    private const string FromFieldParam = "fromfield";

    public void Process(GetLookupSourceItemsArgs args)
    {
        // check if "fromfield" is available in the source
        if (!args.Source.Contains(FromFieldParam))
        {
            return;
        }

        // get the field
        var parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(args.Source);
        var fieldName = parameters[FromFieldParam];

        // set the source to a query with all items from the other field included
        var items = args.Item[fieldName].Split('|');
        args.Source = this.GetDataSource(items);
    }

    private string GetDataSource(IList<string> items)
    {
        if (!items.Any()) return string.Empty;

        var query = items.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, itemId) => current + string.Format(" or @@id='{0}'", itemId));
        return string.Format("query://*[{0}]", query.Substring(" or ".Length));
    }
}
```

You have to specify which field is your "Source" field within the `Droplink` source with `fromfield=<SourceField>`:

[image]

At the end you need to configure this pipeline processor:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getLookupSourceItems>
        <processor  patch:before="processor[1]"
                    type="Website.LookupItemsFromField, Website" />
      </getLookupSourceItems>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://getfishtank.ca/blog/using-item-field-as-a-data-source-in-sitecore

Basically you will be able to set the datasource of one field to another.