# Sitecore data source from selected items in multilist

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a page with a multilist

[image: My Multilist]

and I want to create a second multilist with the selected values of the previous list (and reflecting the changes one the second multilist when the first one is modified).

- Activity
- Lonely planet Denmark

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to link a droplink to a Treelist in Sitecore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784121/how-to-link-a-droplink-to-a-treelist-in-sitecore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extend MultiListEx field and and add your dynamic source At DoRender event, your code should be like:

```cs
public class CustomMultiList : MultilistEx
{
  private void GenerateDynamicDatasource()
  {
    //write some code to get the selected IDs from the first multilist field
    //build a string with this query format :
    // string EncludedIDsQuery = "@@id == '[First Selected Guid]' or @@id == '[secondSelected Guid]'" and so on
    this.Source = "query:" + this.Source + "/*[" + EncludedIDsQuery+ "]";
  }

  protected override void DoRender(output)
  {
    this.GenerateDynamicDatasource();
    base.DoRender(output);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Update**

Keven has more reusable solution, and i think it will work for your case too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25785363/2074649

Comment: I would not create a custom field here, I would use the `getLookupSourceItems` pipeline, as I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25785363/2074649

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl Great solution, but would not this be applied on all multilist fields, i think Helder only need it on one field

Comment: No, the code only the source of your field contains a `fromField` configuration. See the image posted. Of course this pipeline processor runs for every list with possible source items, but the first if statement directly returns.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl If thats the case, then its a better solution and more reusable