# Custom field datasource as multilist values in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I want to make the selected values of a multi list as my data source for drop list in site core, How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I am using sitecore 7.5 was thinking to implement it using custom field but could not find an option to do so in 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the top answer on this question:
[How to link a droplink to a Treelist in Sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784121/how-to-link-a-droplink-to-a-treelist-in-sitecore/25785346)

This example explains how you can populate a droplink to a treelist and I think this approach should work for multilist and droplist as well.